# copy a single row from one datatable to other

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datatable, datarow

I have two datatables one has few rows other is empty.
I am running a loop over first one to copy some of the rows to another table.
I am getting error 'The row already belongs to another table'.

Is there any way to copy DataRows one by one to other DataTable.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure that if you show the code you will get a very fast (and right) answer

Comment: sorry Steve, I cant publish code due to some reason. btw got the answer, thanks all

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use

```
newtable.ImportRow(oldtable.Rows[i])
```

where `i` is the desired row number.

as explained in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308909/en-us

Answer (score 3):

copy the ItemArray, of course just works when the  columns are the same

```
var dtCopyTo = new DataTable();
foreach(var rowCopyFrom in dtCopyFrom.Rows)
{
    var updatedDataRow = dtCopyTo.NewRow();
    updatedDataRow.ItemArray = rowCopyFrom.ItemArray;
    dtCopyTo.AddRow(updatedDataRow);
}
```

ps: code is typed without ide so check syntax pls